# How to detect that iOS locale is in a place where numbers use comma instead of period between whole & fractional parts?

Tags: ios, locale, nsnumberformatter

I have a special requirement to learn whether the current locale uses comma-based or period-based numbers. Is there a simple way to learn this?

Answer (score 10):

```
- (NSString *) getDecimalSeparator
{
return [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator];
}
```

Will return current separator. I use it for generating valid CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking a look at the NSNumberFormatter class:

[NSNumberFormatter class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Programming guide on doing this through CoreFoundation:

[Data formatting programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDataFormatting/Articles/dfCreatingCFNumberFormatters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002342-SW1)

Its good that you are spending time on this, in my application I made use of my own timestamp format, while the system allows you to pick your own timestamp format... needless to say I had some angry users.